# Nuxt - define a const once and which can use across all pages

Tags: vuejs2, shopify, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement Shopify JS SDK in Nuxt

So this is what I did, a plugin

```
// plugins/shopify.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
import Shopify from 'shopify-buy'

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  app.shopify = Shopify.buildClient({
    domain: 'aaa.myshopify.com',
    storefrontAccessToken: 'aaa'
    });
}
```

nuxt config

```
//nuxt.config.js
plugins : [{ src : '~/plugins/shopify', ssr: false}]
vendor : ['shopify-buy']
```

index

```
asyncData ({ app }) {
    return app.shopify.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
        // Do something with the products
        console.log(products);
        return { products : products }
    });
}
```

The result is

> TypeError Cannot read property 'product' of undefined

But it works if I removed the asyncData, refresh my page, and add the code back without refreshing.

I believe this has something to do with the lifecycle.

Can anyone please tell me if I'm doing it the right way, or there's other proper way to define such const which can be use across pages, components etc

And if this is the right way, what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

My reference are Nuxt guides as well as examples.
I tried google around but can't locate what I need, or maybe I just didn't get the right keywords.

Answer (score 2):

#### FROM [DOCUMENTATION](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/)

> Nuxt.js lets you create environment variables that will be shared for
>   the client and server-side.

To do this, you can use the [`env` property](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/):

**`nuxt.config.js`**:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

Then to access it from anywhere, just use it like so:
`process.env.baseEnv`

For example, in an axios plugin:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.baseUrl
})
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice. I have tried it out, and it does help. Right now I just have to import the plugin in the pages to use. Just curious, this is the proper of doing it?

Comment: @NinjoeQuah yes, that comes straight from the nuxt documentation